# Should I declare conversion operators explicit in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

In C++11,it is recommended:

1. to explicitly define our own copy/move constructors, so that the compiler does not do it itself (according to [[1]](http://www.apibook.com/blog/)).
2. to explicitly declare one-argument constructors as explicit, to avoid implicit conversions (according to [[2]](http://www.deitel.com/Books/C/CHowtoProgram9e/tabid/3644/Default.aspx)).

Should one, in this train of thought, declare conversion operators `explicit` to prevent the compiler from using them to perform implicit conversions?

Comment: "to explicitly define our own copy/move constructors" Umm, no. Where did you hear that? Or do you count `= default` as defining?

Comment: Where does recommendation #1 come from? For most cases, compiler-generated copy and move constructor is fine. It is just classes that manually manage resources such as memory that ever need to define their own.

Comment: I would completely disagree with point 1. Follow the [Rule Of Zero](https://turingtester.wordpress.com/2015/06/27/cs-rule-of-zero/) unless your are writing a resource-managing class.

Comment: It depends whether you want to allow implicit conversions or not. (And if not you could consider a named function rather than an explicit conversion operator).

Comment: I think this would be a good question if it just asked "when to declare conversion operator explicit".

Comment: part 1 is false. part 2 is somewhat common

Comment: Regarding your source for claim #1 - going by the Reddy's books which I've read, I wouldn't trust his advice on C++ design. General design, why not; but for the C++ specifics, it never sounded good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In C++11,it is recommended:
>
> 1. to explicitly define our own copy/move constructors, so that the compiler does not do it itself.

Whoever came up with that recommendation, it is wrong. Whenever the default implementation fits your needs, use it. You'll probably not going to get it better yourself.

> 2. to explicitly declare one-argument constructors as explicit, to avoid implicit conversions.

The [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md) say "By default, declare single-argument constructors `explicit`". You might prefer to have implicit construction in some cases (e.g. `std::string` has from `const char*`). Leave out the `explicit` declaration in those cases.

> Should one, in this train of thought, declare conversion operators explicit to prevent the compiler from using them to perform implicit conversions?

There is no really good point in making them explicit. That would mean, that the conversion can only be used with a cast. Casts are harder to read than getter function calls. Write conversion operators, when you want implicit conversion, write getters when you want explicit conversion.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is "no, you should not". Explicit conversion operators were added to the language to deal with a specific issue described below. When you are not dealing with that specific issue, you should either add an explicit copy constructor to the destination class, or write a named function instead of the conversion operator (as in [`c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) of `std::string`).

Let's step back and consider conversion in general. When you need to write a conversion code to go from `A` to `B` you have two options - you can define a one-argument constructor, like this

```
struct B {
    B(const A& a);
};
```

or you can define a conversion operator, like this:

```
struct A {
    operator B() const;
};
```

The first approach has allowed the explicit/implicit control prior to C++11. However, it was not available in two situations:

- You own type `A` but you do not own type `B`, or
- You own type `A`, but type `B` is *primitive*

According to the [draft paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2333.html) for the explicit conversion operators of C++11, it is these two cases that the committee was addressing when they argued for adding the explicit conversion operator to the language. All other situations were already covered by (1) implicit and implicit copy constructors, (2) implicit conversion operators, and (3) named member functions.